# Executing code when ASP.NET site is completely done rendering

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, label, repeater

I've looked around and tried to find a solution but haven't been able to find one I could adapt to my issue.

Basically I got a repeater pulling paths to images out of a SQL database, with it there are 3 value defining height, width, and price, this is shown with 3 labels under the image. However I don't want the label to show if the values are 0, so I wrote this foreach to sort it:

```
foreach (RepeaterItem Rep1 in Repeater1.Items)
{
        //assigns a temporary variable the value of the control we find.
        Label nullPris = (Label)Rep1.FindControl("PrisLabel");
        Label nullHeight = (Label)Rep1.FindControl("HeightLabel");
        Label nullWidth = (Label)Rep1.FindControl("WidthLabel");

        //Checks if the lable has the text we're looking for.
        if (nullPris.Text == "0,00 Kr.-" || nullPris.Text == "0.00 Kr.-")
        {
            //If it has, stop rendering the label.
            nullPris.Visible = false;
        }

        if (nullHeight.Text == "Højde: 0,00 cm" || nullHeight.Text == "Højde: 0.00 cm")
        {
            //If it has, stop rendering the label.
            nullHeight.Visible = false;
        }

        //Checks if the lable has the text we're looking for.
        if (nullWidth.Text == " Bredde: 0,00 cm" || nullWidth.Text == "Bredde: 0.00 cm")
        {
            //If it has, toggle the visibility..
            nullWidth.Visible = false;
        }
}
```

The code itself works as intended, however I've run into 2 issues:

- If I call the code in any of the `Page_Events` it doesn't work, the code runs but doesn't find the repeater so skips the rest entirely, it dosen't matter if I put it in `Page_Load` or `Page_Unload`, both seems to be executed before the repeater has done its job.
- Secondly I got around this by calling the code via `OnLoad` on the labels themselves, but then the last loaded item isn't affected, this happens regardless of the amount of items in the database.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried the PreRender event?

Comment: PreRender produces the same result as any other Page_event I've tried, that is to say, nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem that didn't require me to wait for the page to load.

I found other people with a similar problem using a For each loop on items created by a repeater, so I took out the loop and instead executed the code each time a new item was bound to the repeater using the OnItemDataBound method, so my revised code looks like this:

```
protected void Repeater1_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{

    {
        //assigns a temporary variable the value of the control we find.
        Label nullPris = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("PrisLabel");
        Label nullHeight = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("HeightLabel");
        Label nullWidth = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("WidthLabel");

        //Checks if the lable has the text we're looking for.
        if (nullPris.Text == "0,00 Kr.-" || nullPris.Text == "0.00 Kr.-")
        {
            //If it has, stop rendering the label.
            nullPris.Visible = false;
        }

        if (nullHeight.Text == "Højde: 0,00 cm" || nullHeight.Text == "Højde: 0.00 cm")
        {
            //If it has, stop rendering the label.
            nullHeight.Visible = false;
        }

        //Checks if the lable has the text we're looking for.
        if (nullWidth.Text == " Bredde: 0,00 cm" || nullWidth.Text == "Bredde: 0.00 cm")
        {
            //If it has, toggle the visibility..
            nullWidth.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if possible try looking at ajax calls/javascript basically you want to fire a function when the document is ready...right?

[A small description of what I'm trying to say](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635577/detect-when-html-has-finished-loading-and-rendering-on-the-page)

Comment: That would be ideal, yeah, I considered doing it from an empty div block at the bottom of the document, I'll give this a shot, thanks!

Comment: No problem bro! if you dont mind please upvote my answer/accept it as "right"